# What happens when shutdown socket with SD_RECEIVE, but peer sends packet? (winsock)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Let's say I use winsock's `shutdown(s, SD_RECEIVE)` for TCP. 
What happens when after the shutdown, the peer sends packets.

According to MSDN,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481.aspx

> For TCP sockets, if there is still data queued on the socket waiting to be received, or data arrives subsequently, the connection is reset, since the data cannot be delivered to the user.

By "reset" does it mean that RST is sent to the peer by the local TCP? which in turn means, there won't be a graceful shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what it means, but only in Windows. On UNIX the packets are acknowledged and thrown away. On Linux they are acknowledged and buffered, which will eventually stall the sender.

Comment: Thank you, 
do you have any reference for more reading perhaps?

Comment: This is the result of my own testing during the writing of E.J. Pitt, *Fundamental Networking in Java,* Springer-Verlag.

Comment: Fabulous. Thank you for the reference! I have one more question. In the quote above it also says "if there is still data queued on the socket waiting to be received". By this, does it mean that RST is sent to its peer regardless of the peer doing anything?

Comment: If there is data already in the socket receive buffer an RST is issued regardless. If there isn't, and data subsequently arrives, an RST is issued.